# Dojo: Adding subnodes to a tree programmatically

Tags: dojo

I am creating a tree in Dojo backed by ItemFileWriteStore. I can add nodes to the root of the tree using newItem(), but I don't know how to add subnodes. How can I get hold of existing nodes and then add subnodes?

Answer (score 1):

[newItem](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dojo/data/api/Write/newItem) can receive a second argument that describes what parent you want to create the new item under.

Comment: I have tried that as per the doc, but I don't understand how this parent description should look like. Do you have an example? Then, the other thing I am struggling with is to get a handle on a specific (existing) item in the tree. I have tried fetchItemByIdentity, but I was wondering if this can be done without a callback function.

Comment: Sorry, the tree I'm using now uses the new dojo.store API (and a custom treeModel to interface with it) so I don't remember precisely what incantations you need to get it to work with the old  data API. As for the fetchItem I think the only way to avoid callbacks would be fiddling with the internal item array (at your own risk)